# Allowing rural, isolated societies to maintain certain industrial capabilities?

Tags: alternate-history, engineering

My society/area is set in a isolated wasteland where the primary income of people is ranching. However, I want my people to be able to at least be able to maintain technology at a 1916 level (the reason for 1916 is because airplanes, balloons, and dirigibles with war-fighting capabilities are integral to the setting).

I realize that during the actual First World War most of these technologies were built in super-massive factories in urban areas with advanced industrial engineering processes. What are some ways I can allow my characters to at least by able to continuously maintain their technology without introducing a modern city or Henry Ford-esque assembly lines?

Comment: Can the individual isolated societies access knowledge from a previous and more advanced society?  Is this a post apocalyptic setting?  If not, each society would need innovators and engineers capable of creating flight technology, which might not be feasible and would definitely not arise simultaneously in multiple geographically isolated communities.

Comment: Just maintain? Or manufacture replacements? Lots of 1916-era aircraft were lost due to rather unremarkable weather and similar boring non-combat causes.

Comment: The nice thing about 1916 level tech is that most of it was manufacturable or improvisible without special tooling.  the large factories existed to create stuff in large quantities.

Comment: Not exactly post-apocalyptic but I think that's a good reference point. They would have access texts/other print knowledge from more advanced people but not the ability to set up their own universities.

Comment: [Tim B's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/99344/29) and specifically its mention of large wing span airplanes made me think of gliders, specifically winch-launch gliders. It's possible to construct a glider out of wood; they can fly quite far and high given the right circumstances (mainly weather); and fixed-wing glider aircraft were built reasonably early. With a glider, you can focus the "engine" efforts on the ground, which means that you can have larger, higher-pressure steam engines without the disadvantages of having to carry all of that weight on board a plane.

Comment: If you want to get rid of big town just get rid of sanitazion, without it cities are impossible to grow without becoming a big open septic fosse mess. Instead to big factories create small manufacurers villages feed by surrounding small farms. WWI and mainly WWII are industrial wars. Keeping industry low means you cannot wage war like those keeping warfare in IX century fashion at best

Comment: For an endeavour in a similar vein, read Jules Verne's [The Mysterious Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Island "The Mysterious Island"). Though the era is earlier than requested, approximately 1870-1880, the heroes were able to build their own railroad on the island, iirc. Sure it was a bit idealistic and the conditions "just right", but with more resources, it might be believable, or at least not stretch the suspension of diesbelief to a breaking point.

Comment: The resource production for, say, belts of machine-gun bullets requires mining, chemistry, metal refining and stamping...and good quality control or it all explodes on one bad day. Seems like that production alone will occupy much of the population. That's *before* you get to machining the guns and building the biplane.

Comment: First, you are not going to be doing ranching (or any kind of farming) in a wasteland, pretty much by definition.  You need productive grazing lands &c.  Second, you need to clarify if this is tech developed ab initio, or if it's using leftover stuff after e.g. urban collapse.  The first really isn't possible; the second would be fairly easy using salvaged materials.  Look at e.g. home built aircraft.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's actually a reasonable level of technology to maintain. The key to it being most things could still be built by one person with the skills.

The early days of aircraft, it's still one man in his shed building a flying machine.

The early days of cars, before Mr Ford and his production lines, small teams on a small scale and often, again, one man in his shed building a car.

While this is late/post industrial revolution era, steam trains crossed the land and dreadnoughts ruled the oceans, for most purposes small scale still worked.

As long as the village still has its blacksmith, carpenter, tailor, and local lord with money to splash on such things, it's reasonable to build cars and small aircraft on a local scale. Building one doesn't require a vast factory, just enough space to work and people with suitable skills.

Comment: Could a local lord with enough money and resource build something like an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatros_D.III for himself. Could a much wealthier lord with several lords below him build something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeppelin_P_Class

Comment: @knowads, the biplane was exactly the sort of thing they were building, the big zeppelin not so much, you'd have to give them really good reason to try it. Mostly they build single/double seat aircraft.

Comment: @Separatrix, I cannot comment on how hard it is to build a simple automobile, but I have some knowledge of tailoring. To produce a simplest garment from scratch you need to know how to 1) grow fibres (plant or animal based); 2) process raw materials (wool is easier but it still requires preparation for spinning); 3) spin thread (let's assume that we hand spinning just to avoid building a spinning wheel). From here let's go with knitting or crocheting just to make things easier and do not build a weaving loom. Someone has to make needles. Their quality will determine the speed and quality of...

Comment: [cont.]... production. Nice, smooth needles will let me knit with much less effort and faster. But, in order to end up with a wearable garment, I need to know how to knit/crochet and how to build a pattern. I listed just 6 steps, which require at least 3 different people (can reduce it to 2, but then it might take a year to make that sweater). Tailoring will include several additional steps and more people. Moreover, there are very few people alive today who have first-hand knowledge of traditional techniques. So, even an experienced tailor may have no idea how to produce cloth or thread

Comment: @Olga, don't forget we're talking period but in period. Aircraft and vehicles were mostly wood framed, controls were crude, engines equally crude. There would have been a wool trade, a cloth trade, my grandfather was a haberdasher not long after the period in question. To a certain extent it was easier to do these things at the time than it is now because the secondary trades were all still in place at a local small scale. The sons of the gentlemen really did build planes in their sheds and barns.

Comment: The requirements for making clothes haven't changed much over the years, to make a wool jumper by hand now is effectively the same as it was 200 years ago. To make a modern car by hand is impossible, as is a modern aircraft, but the dangerous and unreliable machines of the time were an entirely different question.

Comment: @Separatrix, I got confused about the period after reading comments. For some reason, I thought it was a post-apocalyptic setting. I still think that you underestimate how many people are involved in the process of making even something technologically simple.

Comment: @Olga, lots of people, but that's because it was a manual labour intensive era. It took a lot of people to bring in the harvest as well, a lot of people to shear the sheep, a lot of people to mine coal, but people were cheap until after the wars. One person could make wooden needles, shear a sheep, card and spin the wool then knit a jumper, but that could be the industry of a whole village (or island) and everyone would be involved come shearing time. The blacksmith is special though, he probably could build a motor car from raw materials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69704/discussion-between-olga-and-separatrix).

Comment: I agree, A man in his barn building an aircraft would be making all of it, possibly down to the bolts (though he'd probably get those from a blacksmith).  The point being that no one would specialize in making just the bolts.  There aren't enough customers for highly specialized parts.

Answer (score 7):

## There is a demographic gap

You mention desired 'rural, isolated societies' in your title, and then contrast that to 'super-massive factories in urban areas.' However, there is a pretty large gap between the two. What about cities of 25,000 people? What about rural areas but with lots of villages near each other?

## Rural areas can be pretty dense

First off, East and South Asian rural areas are very dense. [Jamui district](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jamui,+Bihar,+India/@24.7558525,85.94067,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x39f22a4bc2a74a23:0x6562e20cf2113710!8m2!3d24.764688!4d86.3376761) in Bihar in India has nothing that could be referred to as an urban area, and some forested hills. It [also has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamui_district) nearly two million people in 3100 km$^2$, a density of over 500 per km$^2$. That is denser than the state of New Jersey or Southeast England, for example.

An example closer to what you are thinking of might be Picardy, north of Paris, which was very populous in the Middle Ages. [Estimates for its population](http://www.athenapub.com/14Picardie.htm) are around 2 million people [in an area of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picardy) 20,000 km$^2$, good for a density of 100 km$^2$; and its largest towns of Amiens, Senlis and Noyon were less than 20,000. This isn't particularly dense by modern standards, yet I can find many examples of early 1900s heavy industry at significantly lower population densities.

## Small city

First off, a large manufacturing plant in a company town doesn't have to be that big. The Granite City Works was an iron kitchenware factory located in company town of [Granite City, Illinois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granite_City,_Illinois) (across the river from St. Louis). Important to our topic, the factory founders required all workers to live in the town they purpose built for it. The factory was founded in 1891, and the town had 3000 people in 1900, and 10,000 people in 1910. So a single plant, even a very large one, could be run in what is really just a small town.

## Semi-rural

The [Curtiss Aeroplane Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_Aeroplane_and_Motor_Company) was the largest airplane manufacturer in the world at the end of WWI, which is pretty directly relevant to your story. This company's second largest factory was in Hammondsport, New York, with an employment of around 3000.  Hammondsport, meanwhile was a town of only 1000. The workers must have come from the surrounding counties. There are three counties within about 30 miles of the city, Steuben, Yates, and Schuyler. These counties in 1910 had about 115,000 people in 5300 km$^2$, about 22 people per km$^2$ in density. Remember, again, that the density of medieval Picardy was around 100 people per km$^2$.

## Low density manufacturing region

The [Lehigh valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehigh_Valley) was one of the cradles of American industry. Coal mining started in the northern hills [by 1818](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisgah_Mountain). More famously, Bethlehem Rolling Mill and Iron company was formed in the valley in 1857 and was by 1904 Bethlehem Steel, the second biggest steel producer in the nation. The steel mills in the Lehigh valley counties of Northampton and Lehigh were fed by anthracite mined in the hills to the north, in Carbon and Schuyler county. Also relevant, there was significant clothing production in the earlier part of this era.

Yet, throughout this period, the population densities in these areas were not outstandingly high. In 1900 in the valley, Northampton and Lehigh counties had about 195,000 people in an area of 1800 km$^2$, about 105 people per km$^2$. The only cities in the valley at the time were Allentown (population 35,000), Easton (25,000), and Bethlehem (7,000).

Meanwhile, in coal country in the hills, there were 220,000 people in 3000 km$^2$, for an overall density of 75 people per km$^2$. The only city was Pottsville, population 16,000.

## Conclusion

Overall, you have one of the major industrial centers on the Earth (at the time) with significant coal and steel production, but with an a population density similar to the Picardy in the Middle Ages, no cities larger than a medieval one, and only about 20% of the population urban.

You can also have significant manufacturing plants in stand-alone cities of 10,000, or low density rural areas. If plants requiring developed supply chains, up to and including even aircraft production, than less developed industries like clothing and food processing should have no problem working on a small scale.

I'd say that overall, it is no problem having advanced industry if you decide there are no large cities. If large cities were infeasible for some reason (recurring epidemics, cultural taboos, godzilla attacks), then it is entirely possible for all 1900s era manufacturing hubs to be less like Chicago and more like the Lehigh Valley.

Comment: This plan assumes a very high level of interconnectedness and coordination which does not work with 'isolated wasteland' as specified by the OP.

Comment: @Olga That is true, but this is a suggestion about how a small adjustment to the initial conditions can make he desired end-state possible.

Comment: yours is a good idea. I am just being pedantic.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: When I wrote my answer I did it with an assumption that we are talking about a post-apocalyptic society that prior to the Event already had all the tech up and running. So, the main problem as I saw it was salvaging, repurposing, jury-rigging, and maintaining machinery that was produced on an idustrial scale before.

Discussion with @Separatrix made me realise that this is not the case. However, @knowads mentions that his society has access to blueprints and manuals. Thus, the main problem is to build infrastructure to maintain a desired level of technology.

In this case, WWI technology in rural isolated societies is impossible without a lot of handwaving and magic. You need a lot of people and developed infrastructure to build and run even a primitive aircraft. You will need oil, metal, wood, cloth, all processed and prepared in a very specific way. Blueprints are just a recipe, but you need a kitchen, appliances, and ingredients to cook a dish.

There is also a question of economic viability. Even if it is indeed possible to build a simple aircraft from scratch in a smithy (which I doubt after reading about [the Wrights engine](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wright_brothers#/Adding_power)), how much time will it take? Can a rural community afford to lose this vessel in a battle?

---

**If it is a post-apocalyptic setting...**

It is unlikely that you will be able to maintain this level of technology with a small and isolated group of people indefinitely. However, if you have your very special people start in a very special location at a very special time the technology might last for a couple of generation.

### 1. Special people

Your people should have the knowledge of these mechanisms and ways to maintain them. You might try a military installation with an engineering research lab. Throw in a couple of historians or WWI history reenactment enthusiasts for a higher level of expertise in WWI technologies.

### 2. Special location

You probably want your location to be warm and dry so the mechanisms last longer. It will be also easier to produce biofuels (either plant oils or animal fat) that most likely will be required to power your tech.

The military base can be a good place because it will have all kinds of supplies. A nearby military history museum might even have some functioning or semi-functioning mechanisms that can be restored. It is also easy to justify the location's remoteness, isolation, and most importantly relative intactness.

### 3. Special time

Even WWI technology requires long manufacturing chains. Raw materials are gathered in one place, processed in another, then the components are manufactured in yet another place, and so on. An isolated group of people will not be able to reproduce these technological chains. It also might not have enough people to fill all specialist positions involved in building even the simplest air vessel.

So, you need your base of operations to be somehow miraculously stocked with various equipment just before the apocalypse. It does not have to be raw materials or ready-to-use details. But it should have enough stuff that can be recycled and repurposed.

Perhaps, if your base were just stocked or, better, received a shipment of old equipment for decommission it would explain the presence of tech and means to maintain it.

---

It will also be critical to maintain mechanised agriculture. Otherwise, the majority of your people will be busy with growing food and there will be no time to build and service tech.

If you want to start manufacturing new things instead of patching up old ones, your population must expand both in numbers and territory. You also will need to come up with new fuels and sources of raw materials. The majority of easily accessible metals and fossil fuels have been mined already. So, it will be a big challenge on its own. Your society will have to rely on biofuels and recycling (plastics, scrap metal, etc.).

Comment: @knowads, I edited my answer since I realised my understanding of your question was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face isn't the construction of the planes themselves; most of these can be done without metal at all, meaning that a metallurgical society can be in its relative infancy and still build the shell of the plane.

That said, you still want metal for ploughs, stirrups, knives etc. That means you need access to ore, but also to coal. Also, 1916 implies that you have access to black powder or gunpowder.

The first part of the answer is that you should have your society near a mountain range. The processes that create mountain ranges (Orogeny) generally do so by tearing the crust and pushing parts of it up, revealing most of the ores and coal close to the surface. If at least part of your lands are near a mountain, then you have easier access to these minerals and the other part of it can be used for agriculture and herds. Blacksmiths have been around for millenia because metallurgy isn't that hard to figure out once you have the materials to use.

Why the mountain? Because if you're maintaining an agrarian culture, you have a limited number of people available in your society that can be productive in something other than food cultivation; especially if you want to keep it that way. But, let's say that you can produce enough ploughs and fencing wire to make it worth while to have a dedicated blacksmith team available, and you also have wood and cloth available to make the aircraft frames with. How do you get it in the air?

This is counter-intuitive I know; but you use steam power. Steam was seen as an impediment to air travel because the power to weight ratio was just not high enough to get planes airborne back in 1916. That said, there are two things that are going to make your society progress whether you like it or not; the internal combustion engine and electricity. So, take them both off the table. If the only power you have access to is steam, then factories and mechanisation can only get so big. After all, you need a LOT of coal to keep things running (we'll assume climate change factors aren't that big because we're dealing with small population counts). That means that you can have an agrarian society with minimal manufacturing industry (limited by the size of steam engines and the availability of coal) which means you also have trains if you want them, but given that you have no other options, you can explore the minima of steam engines as well as the maxima.

What that means is that with the right alloys, you can make a steam engine that is capable of powering a plane for a limited time. The trick here is not to make it too high a pressure (that just adds extra weight to contain it) but you need to carry more water. You'd end up with low power, low maneuvering planes with sufficient range for defensive work using steam. These would not be high performance fighters; they'd have large wing spans and be cumbersome so their best application would probably be bombing runs and the like, but again that would be limited to the tensile strength of the airframe (which in wood isn't that great).

This also alleviates the need for additional industries to drill for (and refine) oil.

Not ideal, but really you don't want ideal; if you're trying to create an upper limit to technological progress, you want people operating on the edge of their technology, not using it as leverage into something new.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible and as pojo-guy implied in a comment WWI tech is conveniently about the max level that can be manufactured small scale in small workshops.

There are a few requirements :

**Knowledge**

Your society does not have the resources to develop this level of technology. They need to have everything pre-developed by the people pre-collapse. So "sacred books of sacred patterns of construction" and "sacred smiths" who can follow the instructions in those books or something similar is needed. The levels of understanding and superstition should roughly correspond to generations since collapse.

This would result in technology and science by rote memorization and superstition which would be rather unlike what we are used to. A good model might be the way fundamentalists read the bible.

There might be few heretics doing small scale experimentation mostly to cope with lack of correct tools and materials, but you should expect most devices to be inferior to their real world models. Although having each device hand crafted by a master craftsman that considers it a sacred duty (or something) would have its own benefits. Especially when comparing to war time rush production. I think expecting improved reliability and durability would make sense.

**Tools, and tools to make tools, and tools to make tools that make tools...**

You get the idea. These are the real reason so much time and economic volume was required to develop this level of technology. So not only need the workshops be equipped with tools to build the devices you want, you will also need to remember the tools to build the tools. Although you could presumably set up a continent wide holy order with monopoly to produce the tools, this doesn't seem to be what you want, so the workshops in towns need to be quite well equipped.

**Materials**

This is bit problematic. While it is possible [to produce steel in small scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wootz_steel) I doubt there is a good reference for using [crucible steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucible_steel) to build modern technology.

You can just forget about aluminum.

If you want aircraft engines you will also need fuel. For your distributed and low density civilization this pretty much means distilled alcohol. This means reduced energy density compared to fuels available in WW1 aircraft, so you should expect reduced performance.